# Ways to manage Cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume I have a dialog with some checkboxes, radio buttons, text inputs etc that represent some options. I open this dialog by clicking some link on the page. I want to be able to save options as well as cancel by clicking Save and Cancel buttons inside the dialog.

Processing Save button looks straightforward - I just go through the controls and get current values. What I wonder about is how I should better control Cancel button. So, I change some options inside the dialog, then change my mind and click Cancel button. Obviously I need to return all controls to their state before changing.

How do I better do this? Should I save current state on dialog loading to some hidden fields or attributes? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a copy of the current state when opening the dialog, modify the copy in the dialog, and when the user presses a button, replace current state with the new state or simply delete the copy accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the built in reset to return the form values to default, then process a save, which would essentially return the state to the original values before changes were made.

Comment: Only issue I can see with this is the Edit -> Save -> Edit -> Cancel workflow.  It would reset all the way to original, no?

Comment: If every time they click edit it reloads the page with their unique info as the value, then it would reset to their info.  If the page never reloads then the reset would go all the way back to the beginning as if they had never edited/saved.

Comment: Yeah, that works if he's posting on Save.  Could work well depending on application.  I was imagining this was all client-side editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the currently saved state within `data` attributes. In HTML such attribute looks like `data-something="some value"`, but you can simply access it from JavaScript. Eg. jQuery has shortcut for it, which looks like `jQuery(element_selector).data('something')`. You can also set it from JavaScript like `jQuery(element_selector).data('something', 'some other value')`.

Using that mechanism you can initially set these values and with each save overwrite them. In case someone clicks "cancel", you will just restore your controls / form elements to the state matching the value you store as data associated with that element.

Just keep in mind such data is associated with DOM elements, so deleting them you will delete data, but it is very clean and flexible approach in such cases.

More:

- on `data-` attributes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/
- jQuery's implementation: http://api.jquery.com/data/